# Only part of img is clickable inside an anchor tag in chrome

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have the following code. Only part of the image is clickable.

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
    <div class="portfolio-item">
      <a>
        <img class="btn img-portfolio project-img-responsive" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#project-modal" src="img/map_image.jpg">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.btn -> bootstrap CSS class
.row -> bootstrap CSS class
.col-md-4 -> bootstrap CSS class
.text-center -> bootstrap CSS class
.img-portfolio {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.project-img-responsive {
    display: block;
    max-width: 50%;
    height: auto;
}
.portfolio-item {
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}
```

The problem is only with chrome. Works fine in mozilla.

What property am I missing out or getting wrong?

Comment: Your code work fine with me ? have a look 
http://jsfiddle.net/Tr4him/ucdL3/

Comment: Can you duplicate this issue in a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Answer (score 1):

Hello try to add attribute Href

```
<a href="#" >
    <img class="btn img-portfolio project-img-responsive" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#project-modal" src="img/map_image.jpg">
</a>
```

it works with me .

Comment: Yes. Did not work. I really doubt if href  property will have any impact on this.

Answer (score 0):

If @DStruOne's suggestion doesn't work trying adding `display: inline-block` to your anchor element.

```
a { display: inline-block; }
```

Comment: I already tried changing display of anchor tag to "inline-block".. did not help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to trigger a modal, then maybe move

```
data-toggle="modal" data-target="#project-modal"
```

to your anchor tag. In my opinion you shouldn't add '.btn' class to your image. Try moving it to anchor tag too.

Comment: Moving those to the anchor tag did not help as well.

Comment: I've tried to reproduce the problem and created Fiddle
        
    http://jsfiddle.net/YFSW2/

Is it, what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I just noticed. The problem is only with chrome. Works fine in mozilla.

Comment: Try validating your markup with W3C validator (http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input), maybe there's some HTML issue?

Answer (score 0):

Given that the JS fiddle works fine, I suspect another (invisible) element on the page is overlapping your image. I managed to fix a problem similar to this by setting the z-index and position (because the first won't work without the second) of the `<a>` tag...

```
position: relative;
z-index: 100;
```